# Group by using parts of the expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
         Name              Count
23feb.01.04.(33.03.03)       1
23feb.09.(12.04.06)          9
23feb.02.09.(25.06)          1
23feb.01.02.04               2
23feb.01.02                 48
23feb.02.13                  4
23feb.01.04.(33.03.10)       1
23feb.01.04.(33.03.06)       1
23feb.02                    48
23feb.02.07                 12
23feb.01.04.(33.03.01)       1
23feb.02.02                  3
23feb.02.04                 11
23feb                      279
23feb.02.06                  3
23feb.03                    83
```

Is there any way to do a `group by` function to get aggregate result for the higher level of the `Name` string? So, the desirable result is like:

```
  Name                     Count
  23feb                     507
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Yes use group by with the string function of SQL `SubString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (row) expression you can query can also be a group by expression:

```
SELECT   SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, '.')), COUNT(*)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, '.'))
```

Comment: So close,Beat by 9 sec.

Comment: I'm starting to understand how it works here! But, your query is still different. Which one works, depends on ALL of the values in the table. That is, all values there ever will be in that table.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `Like` wildcard you can use `LEFT`

```
  SELECT  LEFT(name,5), COUNT(*)
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY LEFT(name,5)
```

Comment: That's it, instead of grouping on a column, you can also group on a function on a column, as what is happening just above here. Using LEFT or SUBSTR is just what you choose. Once you group by it, it becomes a candidate to be put in the SELECT section, like also displayed.